# Using python request with a big list of proxies

Tags: python, web, proxy, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to create a program that uses a list of proxies iteratively so each proxy will be used from beginning to finish then starting all over again. The way to use proxies in request seems to be like following.

```
proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : "http://177.86.8.166:3128", 
              "http" : "http://177.223.187.126:3128" 
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

I have a big list of proxies like below.

```
177.86.8.166:3128
177.69.237.53:3128
177.223.187.126:3128
177.101.172.14:3128
177.185.114.89:53281
177.128.192.125:8089
177.128.210.250:8080
```

I have thought about using a loop to append all these proxies in a proxyDict var in memory. Than run my program. Is this the best way to do. I also want to repeat a request in case the proxy fails to work properly with another proxy and this should continue until request is made successfully. I am thinking of using a try catch block for this is this the best way to do it? Or is there a better way.